# Visual Studio Code not compiling all *.ts files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup VSC with Typescript, but I can't get VSC to compile all *.ts files with Ctrl + Shift + B.
I have gone through numerous tutorials on how to setup Typescript with VSC and I didn't manage to succeed.

My tsconfig.json file (located in root) looks like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "amd",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outFile": "all.js"
    }
}
```

And tasks.json file (located in root/.vscode):

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc", // it should be tsc.cmd instead of tsc
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "args": [ ],
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

When I put "args": ["${file}"], then it compiles the current file, not in all.js, but in typescript-file-name.js, like it ignores tsconfig file.

Can VSC compile all *.ts file with its own task runner and how to set it up?

**UPDATE**
As I've said, I've tried many tutorials that said to leave args empty, to put "-p", "." inside it, to use npm install -g typescript, to check path variables... None of that worked.

Thing that was missing was tsc.cmd in tasks.json for the command.

If anyone knows, I would like to know why it wasn't working with "command": "tsc" when even the comment in the tasks.json file for that command line states:

```
// The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
```

Comment: have you installed typescript as global package? check by running tsc -v command in command window

Comment: I have installed Typescript with "npm install -g typescript" and tsc -v brings me back version number of 1.8.5. It works with "tsc.cmd" instead of just tsc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should change the args command like something like this.
Notice I changed my command to point at a local tsc version but that doesn't really matter. The important stuff is in the `args` option: `["-p", "."]`

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "${cwd}/node_modules/.bin/tsc.cmd",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "args": ["-p", "."],
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Comment: For the command section I get "The system cannot find the path specified" and with args added I didn't get *.js file generated at all and no errors either. Like I didn't changed a thing. Something is not right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tsconfig.json is set to use tsc, the solution to this problem is: 
in command mode in your project root folder,  enter **tsc-w**